# Option strict disallows late binding

Tags: vb.net, binding, class-library

```
Private Sub btnInsert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
    Dim coinnn As New Coin()

    ' decalres variables and link them to the class library
    coinnnn.Metal.Silver = "Silver"
    coinnnn.Metal.Platinum = "Platinum"
    coinnnn.Metal.Palladium = "Palladium"
    coinnnn.Metal.Zinc = "Zinc"
    coinnnn.Metal.Nickel = "Nickel"
    coinnnn.Metal.Platinum = "Platinum"
    coinnnn.Metal.Gold = "Gold"
    coinnnn.Metal.Copper = "Copper"
    coinnnn.Currency.USD = "USD"
    coinnnn.Currency.JPY = "JPY"
    coinnnn.Currency.CHF = "CHF"
    coinnnn.Currency.CAD = "CAD"
    coinnnn.Currency.EUR = "EUR"
    coinnnn.Currency.GBP = "GBP"

    ' adds the values to the radio boxes
    If radZinc.Checked Then
        radZinc = coinnnn.Metal.Zinc
        If radSilver.Checked Then
            radSilver = coinnnn.Metal.Silver
        ElseIf radPlatinum.Checked Then
            radPlatinum = coinnnn.Metal.Platinum
            If radPalladium.Checked Then
                radPalladium = coinnnn.Metal.Palladium
                If radNickel.Checked Then
                    radNickel = coinnnn.Metal.Nickel
                ElseIf radGold.Checked Then
                    radGold = coinnnn.Metal.Gold
                    If radCopper.Checked Then
                        radCopper = coinnnn.Metal.Copper
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    ' adds the values to the drop-down list
    If cboCurrency.SelectedValue.USD Then
        cboCurrency = coinnnn.Currency.USD
        If cboCurrency.SelectedValue.EUR Then
            cboCurrency = coinnnn.Currency.EUR
        ElseIf cboCurrency.SelectedValue.GBP Then
            cboCurrency = coinnnn.SelectedValue.GBP
            If cboCurrency.SelectedValue.JPY Then
                cboCurrency = coinnnn.Currency.JPY
                If cboCurrency.SelectedValue.CHF Then
                    cboCurrency = coinnnn.Currency.CHF
                ElseIf cboCurrency.SelectedValue.CAD Then
                    cboCurrency = coinnnn.Currency.CAD
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

I am using a class library and I keep getting the error option strict disallows late binding. Need help for this school assignment. Thank you.

Comment: Not enough info.  Is `Coin` defined in the class lib?  What are those `Metal` and `Currency` assignments doing?  You ought not have to tell the class those types of things.  Where is the error?  If the things like `radZinc` are check boxes/UI controls you cant convert or assign something else to them as you are doing.  Your If blocks are also not going to work like you think.  IF `radZinc` is not checked for instance nothing at all will get assigned - that *arrow pattern* is always a danger signal

Comment: Yes the coin is the class and currency and metal are enums

Comment: Enums are integral/numeric types so assigning text to them ought to fail.  An Enum is defined at compile time, so you dont need to update, inititalize or "link"  them...your class however might expose them (`Public`) so the UI code is playing by the same rules.  Still no idea where the error is. (radio buttons (?) do not have a value so it is not clear what those bad If blocks are trying to do - apparently link each to an Enum item? ).

Comment: I need to pull up the users answer from the enum in the class library when the user clicks a certain metal and currency.

Comment: Keep in mind we were not there in class and dont have the assignment handy. All we know is what you tell us which heretofore is far, far too little. I'll **guess** that when they click a metal you want to create a coin of that metal? **Maybe** `click a metal` means those radio buttons so they pick metal and currency? Either way, the UI code does not assign text to numeric enums. Sorry, but you need to make it easier to help you. Perhaps read [ask]

Comment: Namespace MyCoin
    Public Class Coin
        Public Year As Integer
        Public Name As String
        Public Weight As Decimal
        Public Enum Currency
            USD
            EUR
            GBP
            JPY
            CHF
            CAD
        End Enum
        Public Enum Metal
            Gold
            Silver
            Platinum
            Zinc
            Palladium
            Nickel
            Copper
        End Enum
        End Class
    End Class
End Namespace

Comment: that is my class library

Comment: You do realize that you still have not told us what line the error is on, right?  You seem confused what an enum is, they are constant values.  [Read  about them here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-6).  If the Coin class is supposed to store a Metal or a Currency value, you are missing some properties too

Comment: There is this same error on all the coinnn.Metal and coinnn.Currency statements in the application. I am confused on how to implement them.

Comment: Study the link in my previous comment...all the other cautions going back 6 hours now still apply.

Comment: Ok thank you I will study it more

Comment: @vgingin The only object I see declared in your code is coinnn and that is early bound. Is the use of an enum required by this assignment? If not, I think you should start again without enums.

Comment: Yes I have to use two enums

Comment: If it is not too long, can you post the actual assignment. Don't worry too much about any of it. You will learn more in your first two weeks on the job than you did in 4 years of college.

Comment: Create a .NET class library project called "yourname's Coin - Common" in the same solution as your GUI collection project
Create a class called Coin in the Common library with the following properties (each with an accessor and a mutator) and methods:
Year : Integer
Name : String
Weight : Decimal
Currency : Enum (declare the enum as well for the currencies you have in the drop-down box)
Metal : Enum (declare this for all the metals too)
IsEncapsulated : Boolean
FaceValue : Decimal
Value : Decimal

Comment: An overridden ToString method that returns all of the coin's data in an easy-to-read format
Add a reference to the Common project from the GUI collection project
Modify the "Insert Coin" button to do the following when clicked:

Comment: Create a new Coin instance and populate its values
Use a series of nested IF-THEN(-ELSE) statements or a SELECT statement to populate the Currency and Metal properties from the drop-down box and radio buttons (i.e., you will have to select which values from the enums correspond to the radio button or selected drop-down item)
Displays the result of the Coin object's ToString method in a popup instead of the data from previously.

Comment: Create a VB.NET Web application (not a "web site") in the same solution as your GUI collection project
Add a reference to the Common project from the Web application project
Duplicate the functionality of the "Insert Coin" form as an ASPX Web page with the following change:
Instead of displaying the results of the ToString method as a popup, use an ASP.NET Label control and change its Text value instead.

Comment: Ty Mary this class is very hard I have aced all my others. Just allot of confusion in this one. I’ve got all the apps up just gotta get the enums down.

Answer (score 0):

After much research I have found that my class library was not correctly referencing and I had to fix visual studio by downloading updates and then I rebuilt the class library and referenced it again. Now it it referencing. I have created a for Each loop and now will figure out how to go through the combo box to get the list of items the user selects from the class library.